# windows forms tabbed pages: start a form on different tabs from the command line

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form i want to start on different tab pages from the command line.
This is because the form can be launched by the time/cron service at date/times the
user specifies.

How can i get the form application context to go to the non default first tab ?

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Environment Args= {0}", args.Count());
        for (int i=0; i < args.Count(); i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}:{1}", i, args[i]));
        }
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form myForm = new DailyDirectories();
        if (args.Count() > 0)
        {
            Application.Run(myForm.??? );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to pass a **parameter** to your form class *or* even set a **property**.

```
Form myForm = null;
if (args.Count() > 0)
{
     // in case args[0] contains the start index for your tabControl
     int tabStartIndex = int.Parse(args[0]);
     myForm = new DailyDirectories(tabStartIndex);          
     Application.Run(myForm);
} else // e.g. start form without index
```

Within your form class you'll have to add/change the source.

```
class DailyDirectories ...
{
    /// add constructor or change default constructor
    pubic DailyDirectories(int tabStartIndex)
    {
       InitializeComponents();
       this.tabControl.SelectedIndex = tabStartIndex;
    }

}
```

Comment: tested, works ! Seems a bit tricky to get the index of a tab page. It is not the same as the Tab index and making is visible, active is not the way to do it. The ordering seems to depend on how it is created, not now you want to order the tabs to the user. Ultimately i would like to reshuffle the tabs to make the most used as the top tab first on left. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: no need to get run or initalize to take a parameter. the environment seems visible everywhere. I liked the load property. Knowing how the events percolate through the code means you don't need to write much code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about tabs, I guess you have a Tabcontrol, so why don't you set the tab page you want in your form's `Load()` event?

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   this.tabControl.SelectedIndex = YourIndex;
 }
```